# WCF Client Endpoint service addresses doubling

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service with an address similar to this: https://subdomian.domain.com/Service.svc/. It works as desired in every way but when the client adds the service references the client's endpoint address generates:
https://subdomian.domain.com/**Service.svc/Service.svc**

Any ideas why? Thanks in advance.

This is my configuration:

```
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SubdomainBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>

      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="XXXX" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>

<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

<services>
  <service name="subdomain.domain" behaviorConfiguration="SubdomainBehavior">
    <endpoint address="SubdomainService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicSecureService" contract="subdomain.IsubdomainService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>

    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://subdomain.domain.com" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```